# How to extract image from google video?

Tags: php, video-capture

Images for every youtube videos are hosted their server. You can image of any frame and can display on your site.
I want to do same with other video sites without using getting ffmmpeg installed. Because my share hosting service will not le me do this.

Please suggest me on the same. I want to do it in PHP

Comment: There's no choice but to buy an ffmpeg hosting, or maybe a VPS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work, at least given two conditions:

1. The video sites don't provide an API for you to extract arbitrary frames from the video. If they do, your solution will be video provider specific.
2. You don't want to write your own video decoder for the codec (for example H.264) in PHP. Note that this would be a extremely difficult task and the decoder would be really slow if implemented completely in PHP.

Point 1 is rather improbable, at least I don't know of any video site that does this. Point 2 is really really a lot of work, I'd say it's impossible without deep and profund knowledge of the video codec.

So I guess, your best starting point is to either drop this feature or use a hoster that offers you ffmpeg.